# Active Directory stops authenticating user

Tags: active-directory, forms-authentication

I've used FBA for my site. Authentication is done using Active Directory.
The login and authentication works perfect but sometimes the login does not work. Then after resetting the same password again, it works well. 
For example, the password is:$2014
Initially, it works well. Then after few days passing, it stops working. Then if I manually reset the password to $2014. It again starts working.

I don't know what is the problem. Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your membership provider has some password expiration setting.

For Active Directory:

1. Go in your domain controller server.
2. Open the tool to manage domain users and groups (this depend from your windows version).
3. Select your user and disable the password expiration. You must have administration permissions to do this.

[example link](http://www.adminsehow.com/2010/03/how-to-disable-password-expiration-on-windows-server-2008/)

In alternative, check if when you create the user don't enable the setting to force user to change the password.

Comment: Can you please add more details about how to do that in AD (since it is clear from the question that this is the membership provider used)? :)

Comment: Go in your domain controller server. Open the tool to manage domain users and groups (this depend from your windows version). Select your user and disable the password expiration. You must have administration permissions to do this. [link](http://www.adminsehow.com/2010/03/how-to-disable-password-expiration-on-windows-server-2008/)

Comment: You can add the steps as an edit to your post, please

Comment: I edit my previous comment ;)

Comment: hi Domenico, password expiration is disabled. The users are created by code at the time of user registration.

Comment: I added an alternative solution.